# Loading Vector Layer PyQGIS Issues

Tags: vector, pyqgis

I am trying to follow PYQGIS documentation for loading a shapefile from inside a script.

http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/intro.html

I was able to set the datasource and run the QgsVectorLayer command from the python console inside QGIS so I am guessing my problem is in the setPrefixPath() portion. Using the 'which qgis' command I got /usr/bin/qgis so that is the path I used. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr/bin/qgis', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

ds = '/home/user/shapefiles/nodes.shp'

nodes = QgsVectorLayer(ds, 'nodes', 'ogr')
if not nodes.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Comment: For what its worth...

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/problem-loading-vector-layer-pyqgis

Solution was to change... 

    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr/bin/qgis', True)

to...

    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)