# How to render a vector layer using a QgsMapCanvas in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I updated this [ShapeViewer Demo](http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/) for QGIS 3 and the layer does not render. All that shows is a white rectangle.

The updated code is [here](https://gist.github.com/michaeltryby/f034273af2c884402cc77dac82f5448a). What am I missing?

Comment: Working on this more, it looks like QgsVectorLayer() is returning an invalid layer.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/problem-loading-vector-layer-pyqgis

Comment: Are you on Windows? How you call python? You should use a bat-file like the one in osgeo4w/bin. See my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277136/46073

Comment: Thanks Andreas, It was related to the environment settings.